# CNAME with Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, dns, azure-blob-storage, cname

I have a domain name that I want to point to my Azure blob storage account, but point to a specific storage container, and even more specifically that storage container's index.html page.  When I go to create the CNAME I can't target a specific container or its index page, the CNAME only allows me to stop at .blob.core.windows.net   vs .blob.core.windows.net/container/index.html.   What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What are you really trying to do, and what do you expect to get ?
Storage accounts are not intended for web hosting, so it's not a good practice to try to use it to host webpages.
Also, about CNAME records, think of them as shortcuts, but only shortcuts to another fully qualified domain name (like blog.stackoverflow.com).
e.g. You can make use of a CNAME to provide name resolution to another domain name which is linked to a resource over internet, but if you need to target some files for example, you can rather also use be it a web server, FTP server, of something alike.

Comment: I realize this, it's simply for a portfolio page, I'd like to be able to reach this page from a specific domain name.

Comment: Thus you can use a free tier azure web app to host your page. It's a better approach. The free tier will give you an azure provided Url, if you need to use your own domain name in the Url, you can switch to a shared tier. Have a good luck 

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, Ill look into that!

Comment: What you want to do is a popular request [which Microsoft has plans to fix](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6417741-static-website-hosting-in-azure-blob-storage)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer because i misunderstood the question.

What you are trying to do, i believe, is not possible. CNAME is a part of DNS records so it is able to map IP address to hostnames. What are you trying to do is called [HTTP redirect](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect) on the web server side.